# it is possible to pause animations?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am using the animations defined in the xml folder anim, I'm trying to make a move the item, pause, and apply another different movement.
To try to explain better, this is the code:

```
 <set>
     <translate
         android: duration = "2000"
         android: fromXDelta = "0%"
         android: fromYDelta = "0%"
         android: toXDelta = "-50%"
         android: toYDelta = "-50%"
         android: zAdjustment = "top" />
 </ set>

 <set>
     <translate
         android: duration = "2000"
         android: fromXDelta = "0%"
         android: fromYDelta = "0%"
         android: toXDelta = "50%"
         android: toYDelta = "50%"
         android: zAdjustment = "top" />
 </ set>
```

... I wish I could take a break before starting the second "translate"
Is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

make them as two different set of animation files and add the animation1 first and then take a pause of some time and then set the second animation to your view.
Else use this 
**android:startOffset="TIME_IN_MILISEC_FOR_DELAY"** in you animation declaration in xml file.

Comment: is there any way to pause and resume this animation on button click?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
<set>
<translate
  android: startOffset: "1000"          
  android: duration = "2000"          
  android: fromXDelta = "0%"          
  android: fromYDelta = "0%"          
  android: toXDelta = "50%"          
  android: toYDelta = "50%"          
  android: zAdjustment = "top" />  
</ set>
```

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html startOffset is the delay in milliseconds before the animation runs, once start time is reached.